# pandas corr with arbitrary function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is there an equivalent of DataFrame.corr that takes an arbitrary function f(x, y) and applies it to all pairs of columns and outputs a matrix? It would be so much more convenient

Comment: arbitrary function is too general so there's none. depending on *f*, you might construct one, e.g., if *f* takes an inner product, df.T.dot(df) handles that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your function as a column before using `corr`.  Assuming your x and y are in the df it would look something like this:

```
df['func'] = func(df['x'], df['y'])
df.corr()
```